# Mongo DB Query does not give desired result

Tags: database-design, mongodb, query, json, syntax

I have two collections in **mongo db.**

- One called **list** with keys id and movieid in it.
- One called **movies** with movieid and Genre in it.

The results I am trying to retrieve are:

Which listid has the most movies of the ‘Comedy’ genre?

I have tried using the query below, but my result is wrong:

```
db.mycollection.aggregate({$group: {_id: "id", count: {$sum: 1}}},{Genre: "Comedy" }).sort({"count": -1})
```

How can I fix this query to get the required result mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps slide the genre upfront. Something like this

```
db.mycollection.aggregate
(
   { $match : { Genre: "Comedy" }},
   { $group : {_id: "id", count: {$sum: 1}}},
   { $sort  : { "count": -1 } }
)
```

Comment: well no it gives me { "_id" : null, "count" : 17 } but I want the count for each id.